# How do i Whitelist my app for Huawei Smartphones within the code?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, whitelist, huawei-developers

I am currently facing the following problem:
I want to create an app which should run in background. I am searching pretty much and developed the PowerGenie from Huawei which kills all background processes but the whitelisted ones. How can I add my app to the whitelist oft Huawei? I've read that Huawei do not accept other developer to be whitelisted... Is there any way? Is there a workaround? Does anyone had/has similar problems and can help me pls?
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Please check whether [Huawei Push Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-pushkit) could meet your requirement. By integrating Push Kit, you can send messages to your apps on users' devices in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   There is no options to whitelist app without do settings. In other words, from settings on Huawei phone you can whitelist your app to make it run in the background. Please follow the steps for the setup in EMUI 9 or above phones: Go to Settings->Battery->App launch, find your app and toggle off the switch next to the app,  then in the displayed Manage manually dialog box, enable Run in background , and then enable Manage Automatically for the app. You done!

•   In case you don’t see your apps in App launch, you need to explicitly enable notifications first in order to display them. Please follow two steps below to activate the notifications of your apps.
Go to Settings->Notifications, find your app and Select the app, enable Allow notifications, and enable Display in status bar, then enable Show in Lock screen notifications.
Go to Settings->Apps->Special access->Battery optimization, change the drop down at the top of the screen to All apps, find your app and select the app from the list and tap on Allow.